# Is it possible to increase the number of ticks shown on the axes of a qic chart?

Tags: r, spc

This is the code for my chart, I want to increase the number of ticks in the X Axis

```
qic(x       = as.Date(SubStrDate, '%d-%m-%Y'),
y           = DNARate, # add fields here
data        = dataset,
chart       = 'i', #chart type
facet       = ~ TumourType,
title       = "SPC Analysis of AVG Days Booked to First Seen",
ylab        = 'Count',
xlab        = 'Date',
x.format    = '%d-%m-%Y',
x.angle     = 90,
x.pad       = 0,
show.grid   = TRUE
```

I tried various things;  nint, breaks

Comment: You haven't mentioned what various things you've tried. Did you try the `breaks` argument? Did you try the `nint` argument? It is a "Number indicating (approximately) the desired number of tick marks on the x axis."

Comment: Thankyou @DuckPyjamas - ref "Various things" I was  in a bit of a rush sorry! I have previously tried nint but not breaks. Trying either of these I get a similar error for each; Error Message:
R script error.
Error in qic(x = as.Date(SubStrDate, "%d-%m-%Y"), y = DNARate, data = dataset,  : 
  unused argument (breaks = 5)
Execution halted

Comment: What package are you using? I got those arguments from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts/. If you get an ‘unused arguments’ error then you’re either using a different package, or you’re using an old version of the package (if those arguments were added in a later version).

Comment: Hi @DuckPyjamas; Thanks so much for your reply again. I am using library(qicharts2) so a more recent version which it would seem has dropped the nint and breaks ; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts2/ - it's the only version supported by PowerBI where I am using the code.